# How should I introduce myself after I moved in to a new place I rented

Tags: word-choice

Hi I was trying to speak to the super of my apartment and I was wondering how I should introduce myself.

Because I rented this place, should I say something like

> "Hi I am a **tenant** living in xxxx and I just moved in"

or

> "Hi I am a **resident** living in xxxx and I just moved in"

Comment: I am just curious: why do you need to introduce yourself (again?) AFTER you rented the place?

Comment: I didn't rent the place from the super of my apartment. He is not my landlord. @virolino

Comment: Why not just say: "Hi, I'm Joji -- I just moved into 7B"?